# How to create/parse a data-structure from attribute names and values of a custom syntax markup-code?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, data-structures, domparser

I need to search for fields and values within a text and turn them into an object.

Example of text

```
// condition 1
<@if VERSION = "A1" || VERSION = "A3">

<@assign CTA = "blue">
<@assign CTA2 = "green">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Hello<br/>World">

<@elseif VERSION = "A2">

<@assign CTA = "red">
<@assign CTA2 = "yellow">
<@assign CTA3 = "brown">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Click <a href='https://example.com' style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;'>here</a>">

<@else>

<@assign CTA = "black">
<@assign CTA2 = "white">
<@assign CTA3 = "pink">

</@if>

// condition 2
<@if VERSION = "A4" || VERSION = "A5">

<@assign CTA = "purple">
<@assign CTA2 = "orange">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Hi <span style='font-weight:bold;'>John</span>">

</@if>


// condition 3
<@if LANG = "en_US">

<@assign TITLE = "English">

<@else>

<@assign TITLE = "French">

</@if>
```

If the condition contains "@assign" must construct an object

code I'm trying

```js
jsonObj = [];

var hidden_text = html_c.replace(/<@IF[\s\S]*?<\/@IF>/gi, function(i) {
  i = i.replace(/<@IF[\s\S]*?>/gi, function(k) {
    var $ogg;
    item = {}

    k = k.replace(/(^(?!.*@IF)|(?<=@IF)).*?((?=\=))/gi, function(x) {
      x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");
      item[x] = [];
      $ogg = x;
      return x;
    });
    jsonObj.push(item);

    item2 = {}
    k = k.replace(/"[\s\S]*?"/gi, function(y) {
      item2[y] = [];
      return y;
    });
    item[$ogg].push(item2);

    return k;
  });

  return i;
});

console.log(jsonObj);
```

```html
<script>
  const html_c = `
<@if VERSION = "A1" || VERSION = "A3">

<@assign CTA = "blue">
<@assign CTA2 = "green">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Hello<br/>World">

<@elseif VERSION = "A2">

<@assign CTA = "red">
<@assign CTA2 = "yellow">
<@assign CTA3 = "brown">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Click <a href='https://example.com' 
style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;'>here</a>">

</@if>

// condition 2
<@if VERSION = "A4" || VERSION = "A5">

<@assign CTA = "purple">
<@assign CTA2 = "orange">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Hi <span style='font- 
weight:bold;'>John</span>">

</@if>

// condition 3
<@if LANG = "en_US">

<@assign TITLE = "English">

<@else>

<@assign TITLE = "French">

</@if>
`;
</script>
```

With this code I can create the first part of the object but I don't know how to go about it. moreover, if there are more than one condition with the same field name (e.g. VERSION) a new object is created, while I would like to make it go and update the existing one.

the result I want to get is this, considering:

1. "VERSION" could have any other name, the script must take the name it finds.
2. the values of the <@assign> variables may contain some html code
3. In the if and elseif conditions there could also be the double operator ==

**case of the first condition**

```
[{
  "VERSION": [{
    "A1": [{
      "CTA": "blue",
      "CTA2": "green",
      "TEXT1": "Hello<br/>World",
    }, ],
    "A3": [{
      "CTA": "blue",
      "CTA2": "green",
      "TEXT1": "Hello<br/>World",
    }, ],
    "A2": [{
      "CTA": "red",
      "CTA2": "yellow",
      "CTA3": "brown",
      "TEXT1": "Click <a href='https://example.com' style='text- 
      decoration:none;color:#000000;'>here</a>",
    }, ],
    "ELSE": [{
      "CTA": "black",
      "CTA2": "white",
      "CTA3": "pink",
    }, ],
  }]
}, ]
```

after, if there is another condition that contains '@assign' the object must be updated:

in the case of condition 2, the field 'VERSION' already exists within the object so it will have to update by adding the values found

```
"A4": [{
  "CTA": "purple",
  "CTA2": "orange",
  "TEXT1": "Hi <span style='font- 
weight:bold;'>John</span>",
    }, ],
"A5": [{
  "CTA": "purple",
  "CTA2": "orange",
  "TEXT1": "Hi <span style='font- 
weight:bold;'>John</span>",
    }, ],
```

in the case of condition 3, the LANG field does not exist in the object and therefore will have to be created

```
"LANG": [{
"en_US": [{
  "TITLE": "English",
    }, ],
  }]
```

the variables declared in the possible <@else> will go to update the already existing object "ELSE"

**Final object**

```
        [{
  "VERSION": [{
    "A1": [{
      "CTA": "blue",
      "CTA2": "green",
      "TEXT1": "Hello<br/>World",
    }, ],
    "A3": [{
      "CTA": "blue",
      "CTA2": "green",
      "TEXT1": "Hello<br/>World",
    }, ],
    "A2": [{
      "CTA": "red",
      "CTA2": "yellow",
      "CTA3": "brown",
      "TEXT1": "Click <a href='https://example.com' style='text- 
      decoration:none;color:#000000;'>here</a>",
    }, ],
    "A4": [{
      "CTA": "purple",
      "CTA2": "orange",
      "TEXT1": "Hi <span style='font- 
    weight:bold;'>John</span>",
        }, ],
    "A5": [{
      "CTA": "purple",
      "CTA2": "orange",
      "TEXT1": "Hi <span style='font- 
    weight:bold;'>John</span>",
        }, ],
    "ELSE": [{
      "CTA": "black",
      "CTA2": "white",
      "CTA3": "pink",
    }, ],
      }],
   "LANG": [{
    "en_US": [{
      "TITLE": "English",
        }, ],
   "ELSE": [{
      "TITLE": "French",
    }, ],
      }],
    }, ]
```

UPDATE

Condition 4

If a new condition calls up an existing field and value pair, the object must update. For example:

```
<@if VERSION = "A1">

<@assign CTA = "black">
<@assign TEXT2 = "Hello world">

</@if>
```

VERSION: "A1" has already been created in the object, so it needs to be updated:

- CTA is already present within it, so the value will be replaced with "black"
- TEXT2 was not yet present, so it will be added

Comment: Your top-level callback function doesn't return anything, so `hidden_text` will replace all the matches with `undefined`.

Comment: If you don't need to replace anything, use `.match(/regexp/gi).forEach()` to iterate over the matches.

Comment: Your repeated reuse of the variable `i` makes this code really hard to follow.

Comment: I know it is a dirty code. can you provide an example?

Comment: An example of using different variable names? Use `i` for the first function, `j` for the second, and so on.

Comment: okay, I meant an example of using forEach to do this task, thank you

Comment: I changed the name of the variables to make it more understandable

Comment: 1/2 ... I doubt the target data-structure the OP is looking for. Though the presented target structure can be entirely described as single pure big object literal, the OP wraps an array around each single sub-object. An array only makes sense if one does want to list items which clearly is not the intention of the OP.

Comment: 2/2 ... Thus the target structure has to be either ... `{ VERSION: { A1: { CTA: "blue", CTA2: "green" }, A3: { CTA: "blue", CTA2: "green" }, A2: { CTA: "red", CTA2: "yellow", CTA3: "brown" } } }` ... or ... `[{ VERSION: "A1", CTA: "blue", CTA2: "green" }, { VERSION: "A3", CTA: "blue", CTA2: "green" }, { VERSION: "A2", CTA: "red", CTA2: "yellow", CTA3: "brown" }]`.

Comment: In addition, a viable solution should not be based on regex alone. I would choose an approach which uses regex in order to create a parsable custom markup (e.g. remove any `@` from the custom tags and ensure always closed `<assign></assign>` tags) where one then can parse an html document from. Querying values from a parsed DOM with element and attribute nodes is easier and more reliable.

Comment: by closing the </assign> tag there would be a conflict in case the value contains html code.

Comment: @Vale46 ... Regarding ... _"by closing the </assign> tag there would be a conflict in case the value contains html code."_ ... of cause not, because whoever provides the html-markup as an attribute value is responsible of escaping the markup properly. But again, please provide example code to your just described scenario.

Comment: you are right Peter, I have updated the post. thank you

Comment: @Vale46 ... Are you still participating in this thread?

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes! i didn't think you would help me again given the difficulty of my request. i'm really grateful!

Answer (score 1):

From one of my above comments ...

> In addition, a viable solution should not be based on regex alone. I would choose an approach which uses regex in order to create a parsable custom markup (e.g. remove any `@` from the custom tags and ensure always closed `<assign></assign>` tags) where one then can parse an html document from. Querying values from a parsed DOM with element and attribute nodes is easier and more reliable.

In order to create parsable markup one needs to ...

- [remove any `@` character](https://regex101.com/r/rxpfho/1) from the provided markup's custom tags.

  ```
  '<@assign CTA3="brown"></@if>'.replace(/(<\/?)@(?=if|elseif|assign)/g, '$1')the provided markup's custom tags.
  ```
- [replace any custom `<assign ...>` tag](https://regex101.com/r/rxpfho/2) with a closed version of itself.

  ```
  '<assign CTA="blue"><assign CTA2="green">'.replace(/<assign.*?>/g, '$&</assign>')
  ```
- [replace any `VERSION` attribute](https://regex101.com/r/rxpfho/3) with a unique `'version'` related name, here with a suffix which uses the index of each matched `VERSION` attribute.

  ```
  '<if VERSION = "A1" || VERSION = "A3">'.replace(
    /version\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"(?:\s*\|\|)?/gi,
    (match, capture, idx) => `version-${ idx }="${ capture }"`
  )
  ```

The result of the above described steps can be passed to a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)'s [parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) method in order to create e.g. an HTML document.

Such a DOM can be regularly queried, for instance by [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). If one [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the retrieved node-lists into arrays, one programmatically can create and aggregate the target data structure via nested [`reduced`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based passages.

```js
const markup = `
<@if VERSION = "A1" || VERSION = "A3">

<@assign CTA = "blue">
<@assign CTA2 = "green">

<@elseif VERSION = "A2">

<@assign CTA = "red">
<@assign CTA2 = "yellow">
<@assign CTA3 = "brown">

</@if>`;

const parsableMarkup = createParsableMarkup(markup);
const versionData = parseVersionData(parsableMarkup);

document.querySelector('textarea').value = parsableMarkup;
console.log(versionData);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; top: 0; width: 50%; min-height: 100%!important; }
```

```html
<script>
function createParsableMarkup(markup) {
  return markup

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/rxpfho/1]
    .replace(/(<\/?)@(?=if|elseif|assign)/g, '$1')

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/rxpfho/2]
    .replace(/<assign.*?>/g, '$&</assign>')

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/rxpfho/3]
    .replace(
      /version\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"(?:\s*\|\|)?/gi,
      (match, capture, idx) => `version-${ idx }="${ capture }"`
    )
    .trim();
}

function aggregateAssignmentData(result, assignmentNode) {
  return assignmentNode
    .getAttributeNames()
    .reduce((data, name) => ({

      ...data,
      [ name.toUpperCase() ]: assignmentNode.getAttribute(name),

    }), result);
}

function parseVersionData(markup) {
  const htmlDoc = (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(markup, 'text/html');

  return {
    VERSION: [
      ...htmlDoc.querySelectorAll('if, elseif')
    ]
    .reduce((result, versionNode) => {

      const assignmentData = [
        ...versionNode.querySelectorAll(':scope > assign')
      ]
      .reduce(aggregateAssignmentData, {})

      versionNode
        .getAttributeNames()
        .filter(name => name.startsWith('version-'))
        .reduce((versionData, versionKey) => {

          const versionName = versionNode.getAttribute(versionKey);

          // - create the version specific data-entry.
          // - since different versions can initially
          //   share one and the same configuration,
          //   assign a copy of the before created
          //   assignment-data to each such version.
          versionData[versionName] = { ...assignmentData };

          return versionData;          

        }, result);

      return result;        

    }, {}),
  };
}
</script>

<textarea cols="34" rows="12"></textarea>
```

***Edit** ... which targets/covers all the additional requirements the OP came up with at a later point.*

In order to fulfill the additional and, at one hand, more generic requirements regarding unknown attribute-names, but also more restricting ones regarding attribute-values, where the latter can contain HTML markup, the above approach has to be changed in terms of ...

- **1)** how a parsable html markup can be still achieved,
- **2)** how the meta target-structure can be created from unknown attribute names of the conditional custom tags `<@if ...>` and `<@elseif ...>`.

Regarding **1)**, the regex patterns from the above posted first example code not only need to be adapted but new ones have to be utilized as well.

One would start with targeting every attribute-name and attribute-value pair of the originally provided custom markup. The used regex ... [`(?<name>[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)\s*=\s*"(?<value>.*?)(?<!\\)"/gus`](https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/1) ... does even match line breaks within a value's content. The string replacement does fix/sanitize each attribute's name-value assignment by removing unnecessary white spaces and line breaks, but most importantly by escaping the value sequence via [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), thus enabling further regex based parsing in the first place ...

```
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/1]
markup.replace(
  /(?<name>[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)\s*=\s*"(?<value>.*?)(?<!\\)"/gus,
  (match, name, value) =>
    `${ name }="${ encodeURI(value.replace(/\n+/, '')) }"`
)
```

The next one, we do already know ... it's [`/(<\/?)@(?=if|elseif|assign)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/2) which, used with the correct replacement, removes any `@` character from the provided markup's custom tags ...

```
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/2]
markup.replace(/(<\/?)@(?=if|elseif|assign)/g, '$1')
```

Third, one does assure the correct closing for every `<assign ...>` tag ... [`/<assign.*?>/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/3) ...

```
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/3]
markup.replace(/<assign.*?>/g, '$&</assign>')
```

Last, one provides a number based suffix to each attribute name of the conditional `<if ...>` and `<elseif ...>` tags ... [`/(?:(if\s+)|\|\|\s*)(?<attrName>[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)(?==")/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/5) ...

```
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/5]
markup.replace(
  /(?:(if\s+)|\|\|\s*)(?<attrName>[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)(?==")/gu,
  (match, $1, attrName, idx) => `${ $1 ?? '' } ${ attrName }-${ idx }`
)
```

... which is necessary in order to guarantee only unique attribute names. This specially treated attribute names will be transformed back into their normal/initial form when the data structure gets parsed from the HTML-document.

Regarding **2)**, one does need the help of yet another regex ... [`/^([\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)-\d+$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/6) ...

```
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/6]
const regXInitialAttrName = /^([\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)-\d+$/u;
```

... in order to verify ...

```
regXInitialAttrName.test(attrName)
```

... and restore the mutated attribute names ...

```
const initialAttrName =
  (regXInitialAttrName.exec(attrName)?.at(1) ?? attrName).toUpperCase();
```

... of the conditional `if` and `elseif` DOM-nodes.

During parsing/aggregating the final data-structure from the HTML-document, there is still another restoration to do ... each uri-encoded value has to be decoded via [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

And the first solution's example code does finally change to the following one ...

```js
const markup = `<@if VERSION = "A1" || VERSION = "A3">

<@assign CTA = "blue">
<@assign CTA2 = "green">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Hello<br/>World">

<@elseif VERSION = "A2">

<@assign CTA = "red">
<@assign CTA2 = "yellow">
<@assign CTA3 = "brown">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Click <a href='https://example.com' 
style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;'>here</a>">

</@if>

// condition 2
<@if VERSION = "A4" || VERSION = "A5">

<@assign CTA = "purple">
<@assign CTA2 = "orange">
<@assign TEXT1 = "Hi <span style='font- 
weight:bold;'>John</span>">

</@if>

// condition 3
<@if LANG = "en_US">

<@assign TITLE = "English">

</@if>`;

const parsableHtmlMarkup = createParsableHtmlMarkup(markup);
const attributeData = parseAttributeData(parsableHtmlMarkup);

document.querySelector('textarea').value = parsableHtmlMarkup;
console.log(attributeData);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
textarea { position: relative; z-index: 1; background-color: #eee; }
.as-console-row-code { background-color: #ddd; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; top: 0; width: 41%; min-height: 100%!important; }
```

```html
<script>
function createParsableHtmlMarkup(markup) {
  return markup

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/1]
    .replace(
      /(?<name>[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)\s*=\s*"(?<value>.*?)(?<!\\)"/gus,
      (match, name, value) =>
        `${ name }="${ encodeURI(value.replace(/\n+/, '')) }"`
    )
    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/2]
    .replace(/(<\/?)@(?=if|elseif|assign)/g, '$1')

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/3]
    .replace(/<assign.*?>/g, '$&</assign>')

    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/5]
    .replace(
      /(?:(if\s+)|\|\|\s*)(?<attrName>[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)(?==")/gu,
      (match, $1, attrName, idx) => `${ $1 ?? '' } ${ attrName }-${ idx }`
    )
    .trim();
}

function aggregateAssignmentData(result, assignmentNode) {
  return assignmentNode
    .getAttributeNames()
    .reduce((data, name) => ({

      ...data,
      [ name.toUpperCase() ]: decodeURI(assignmentNode.getAttribute(name)),

    }), result);
}

function parseAttributeData(markup) {
  const htmlDoc = (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(markup, 'text/html');

  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gI0egU/6]
  const regXInitialAttrName = /^([\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)-\d+$/u;

  return [
    ...htmlDoc.querySelectorAll('if, elseif')
  ]
  .reduce((result, conditionalNode) => {

    const assignmentData = [
      ...conditionalNode.querySelectorAll(':scope > assign')
    ]
    .reduce(aggregateAssignmentData, {})

    conditionalNode
      .getAttributeNames()
      .filter(attrName => regXInitialAttrName.test(attrName))
      .reduce((attrData, attrName) => {

        const initialAttrName =
          (regXInitialAttrName.exec(attrName)?.at(1) ?? attrName).toUpperCase();

        const assignmentGroup = (attrData[initialAttrName] ??= {});

        const key = conditionalNode.getAttribute(attrName);

        // - create the attribute specific data-entry.
        // - since different conditional attribute entries
        //   can initially share one and the same configuration,
        //   assign a copy of the before created assignment-data
        //   to each such data-entry.
        assignmentGroup[key] = { ...assignmentData };

        return attrData;          

      }, result);

    return result;        

  }, {});
}
</script>

<textarea cols="43" rows="12"></textarea>
```

Comment: great, that's the concept of the result. there are some problems though: "VERSION" could be named in other ways too, and the script should take the name it finds. the values of the "assign" variables can also contain html code, and this script will "break" if it finds it because at the first html tag it does a replace with </assign>. how can it be modified to make it work? thank you for support

Comment: @Vale46 ... [You're running again into the issue of not providing all the necessary requirements with your initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77997912/javascript-create-an-object-by-searching-for-fields-and-values-using-regular-exp). Please do always declare any acceptance criteria upfront. And regarding the most crucial information ... _"the values of the "assign" variables can also contain html code"_ ... How can one omit such a code-breaking (in terms of parsers) scenario at all? Please provide additional example code which reflects all the new requirements.

Comment: @Vale46 ... Regarding the code changes according to your changed requirements, are there any questions left?

Comment: @PietroSeliger wow great job! thank you very much for your help. I've tested the code and it seems to work fine, but there would be some adjustments to make. i think i made the mistake of forgetting something again... i'm trying to study your code to get there myself but it's not easy.

Comment: What I should add is:

1. make the field recognition work even if there is the double operator (e.g. VERSION == "A1")
2. Also recognize <@else> if it is present. In this case the following would be added to the object: ELSE : { ... the @assign's }
3. If an already created field and value pair is queried again in a subsequent condition, the object must update itself by adding any new variables created.

Comment: @Vale46 ... What I do not understand is that you keep repeating the behavior of not giving the full picture at once. Every time I provide a solution to the current requirement, you come up with yet additional conditions. The question is, if I provide a solution to the new requirement/s does it stop you from repeating the pattern again?

Comment: @Vale46 ... In addition, this is not how SO works or how one does ask questions. My suggestion. You either accept the so far provided answer or not. Regardless of that, you come up with an entirely new Q which ... **1)** shows  _**your own effort**_ like the approach or solution you came up with so far ... **2)** addresses in a very clear way what's still missing and where you couldn't succeed. I'm doing this because the current state of the many times refactored answer is rock solid in terms of the requirements, the approach itself and its implementation. From there everyone can work the way.

Comment: you are absolutely right. your answer is valid. my intention was to implement your code by adding the missing things, unfortunately i am not succeeding. the requirements i added yesterday should complete the situation. thank you very much for your efforts